# emacs 24 gud-mi gdb questions

Tags: emacs, emacs24, gud

I am having niggling issues using Emacs v24's gud-mi interface with gdb. I hope someone here can help me out, Google hasn't been much help (probably because of very generic terms)

I use gdb in Emacs thusly: gdb -i=mi --annotate=0

Questions:

1) One of the issues I have seen is that the gdb prompt is not always displayed (you are stuck on a new line without a prompt not knowing whether it is processing something, or waiting for your input). I initially had --annotate=3 and the problem was worse, with --annotate=0, the prompts appear much better, but there still are a few times when the prompt goes missing.

Is there any setting to make sure the prompt is not getting lost?

2) Another "issue" is that I would like gud-gdb to ask me confirmations when I restart the executable, say by mistakenly pressing <r><enter> or just pressing <enter> when my previous command was run (similarly for some big actions like quit, attach etc). Is there a setting to get this behavior?

Platform: RHEL5.0

Thanks for your time and comments!!

Answer (score 0):

A hack for the second issue:

```
(defadvice gdb-send (before ask activate)
  (when (and (string-match "^r" string)
         (null (y-or-n-p "Really run?")))
    (setq string "show version")))
```

The argument `string` which is overwritten is the string sent to gdb.
If `run` is not confirmed it is replaced with the relatively harmless command `show version`. Just a bit noisy.

I think you get the idea.